# TYPO3: Use TCA.php to build Frontend Forms?

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3

I'm searching for a solution, to build a frontend form from the TCA.php of my TYPO3 extension.

Is there any way, to select TCA.php values, from my extension Class? I want to build a select-element with values of the TCA.php file.

Would be amazing, if someone could give me some advice :)

Comment: TCA.php? TYPO3? Maybe you can generalize what you want so it isn't so product specific, cuz I've never heard of either of those things.

Comment: It's a product specific question..

Answer (score 5):

TCA is globally available. You can select any table configuration (TCA) by using the GLOBAL variable. For example, TCA for normal content (tt_content) can be found inside

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']

TCA holds the entire table configuration, if you want to see all of it I suggest you simply print_r() the configuration of the table you would like to see.

The configuration for each field inside a table is stored in

$GLOBALS['TCA']['TABLENAME']['columns']['COLUMNNAME']

If a TCA is not yet loaded, you can load it manually with the following command:

t3lib_div::loadTCA('TABLENAME');

This should help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

We use the wil_frontendedit extension to do this.  It has basic validation and some other tricks.  Front end forms in typo3 are historically a pain, and there are 10 different modules/ways to generate them.